# Angular/CSS - Animate shifting of content when new elements are dynamically added

Tags: angularjs, css, ionic-framework, css-transitions, ng-animate

Angular animation noob here.

I can successfully animate content onto the page using `ngAnimate`. However, when my new content slides in, all of the content below it jumps down to its new position. Likewise, when the new content is removed the following content jumps back up. Is there an angular way to animate the new position of the following content?

```
<button class="button" ng-if="typingResponse">
    Submit!
</button>
<div class="response-section">
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Response</span>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </label>
</div>


.button.ng-enter {
  -webkit-animate: slideInLeft 1s;
  animation: slideInLeft 1s;
}
.button.ng-leave {
  -webkit-animate: slideOutLeft 1s;
  animation: slideOutLeft 1s;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice gif animation, unfortunately it's worthless without the real html+css or better yet - a working example

Comment: This space is created because there is an element at the final position waiting for the animation to end. When  it does the opposite, it makes that element disappear.

You will need to animate first the box, and after that animation been completed, start your animation. The opposite needs to be done to your second animation.

Comment: @AlonEitan added some of the code

Comment: @klauskpm do you have any advice on how to do that? If I want to animate the "Response" box first, I would need to know the height of the incoming "Submit" button. However, at the point when I would want to perform this animation the button is not yet on the DOM.

Comment: Ok. I've given a second thought and maybe some easier solution for you. Create a `div` or any element of your choise, and set it's height to have a `transition` on CSS. The content would be that submit button, so when created, the outter box(the div you created) would do an animation to fit it's content, or that's how it should be.

Comment: @klauskpm awesome! took your advice and came up with the solution below. thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@klauskpm got me most of the way there, and [this blog post](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animating_height/) was the missing piece.

Solution:

1. Put the button inside of a div
2. Set the initial `max-height` of the div to `0px`
3. Specify a transition on the div's `max-height` property
4. When the button is to be displayed, increase the `max-height` property of the div

Updated code:

```
<div class="button-container" ng-class="{'has-button': typingResponse}">
  <button class="button" ng-if="typingResponse">
    Submit
  </button>
</div>
<div class="response-section">
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Response</span>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </label>
</div>

.button.ng-enter {
  -webkit-animate: slideInLeft $slide-dur;
  animation: slideInLeft $slide-dur;
}
.button.ng-leave {
  -webkit-animate: slideOutLeft $slide-dur;
  animation: slideOutLeft $slide-dur;
}


.button-container {
  max-height: 0px;
  transition: max-height $slide-dur linear;
  -webkit-transition: max-height $slide-dur linear;
}

.button-container.has-button {
  max-height: 100px;
}
```